# Set git config for a group instead of user or systemwide

Tags: linux, permissions, configuration, git, user-management

We have configured `git config --system init.templatedir /path/` on our system to automatically create required githooks for each new repository created via `git init`. However, there is another group of users which do not need this custom templatedir (and may even not have read permissions for the set `/path/`). It could be individually deactivated for each user via `git config --system init-temlatedir /usr/share/git-core...`, but it would need to be remembered for any user beeing added on the system.

Is it possible to set a git config for a group of users (something "between" `--system` and `--global`)?

The only solution I see for our situation is to use `--global` for each user, but this has the potential of forgetting to set the option if a new user was created and therefore missing to copy our hooks in new repositories.